# How to inject Material-UI stylesheets into a jest/react-testing-library test?

Tags: jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

It seems that if you don't inject Material-UI stylesheets into a jest/react-testing-library test then jsdom will fail to get the correct styles from your components (e.g. running `getComputedStyle(component)` will return the incorrect styles for the component).

How you properly setup a jest/react-testing-library test so that the styles are correctly injected into the test? I've already wrapped the components in a theme provider, which works fine.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, it seems that it's a limitation with Jest/RTL

Answer (score 8):

As a workaround reinserting the whole head (or the element where JSS styles are injected) before assertion seems to apply styles correctly with both `getComputedStyle()` and react testing library's `toHaveStyle()`:

```js
import React from "react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

test("test my styles", () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(
    <div data-testid="wrapper">
      <MyButtonStyledWithJSS/>
    </div>
  );
  const button = getByTestId("wrapper").firstChild;
  document.head.innerHTML = document.head.innerHTML;
  expect(button).toHaveStyle(`border-radius: 4px;`);
});
```

**This will still fail though when you're using [dynamic styles](https://cssinjs.org/react-jss?v=v10.1.1#dynamic-values), like:**

```js
myButton: {
  padding: props => props.spacing,
  ...
}
```

That's because JSS uses [`CSSStyleSheet.insertRule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) method to inject these styles, and it won't appear as a `style` node in the head. One solution to this issue is to hook into the browser's `insertRule` method and add incoming rules to the head as style tags. To extract all this into a function:

```js
function mockStyleInjection() {
  const defaultInsertRule = window.CSSStyleSheet.prototype.insertRule;
  window.CSSStyleSheet.prototype.insertRule = function (rule, index) {
    const styleElement = document.createElement("style");
    const textNode = document.createTextNode(rule);
    styleElement.appendChild(textNode);
    document.head.appendChild(styleElement);
    return defaultInsertRule.bind(this)(rule, index);
  };
  // cleanup function, which reinserts the head and cleans up method overwrite
  return function applyJSSRules() {
    window.CSSStyleSheet.prototype.insertRule = defaultInsertRule;
    document.head.innerHTML = document.head.innerHTML;
  };
}
```

Example usage of this function in our previous test:

```js
import React from "react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

test("test my styles", () => {
  const applyJSSRules = mockStyleInjection();
  const { getByTestId } = render(
    <div data-testid="wrapper">
      <MyButtonStyledWithJSS spacing="8px"/>
    </div>
  );
  const button = getByTestId("wrapper").firstChild;
  applyJSSRules();
  expect(button).toHaveStyle("border-radius: 4px;");
  expect(button).toHaveStyle("padding: 8px;");
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I am using dynamic styles, and my Jest tests using `toHaveStyle ` kept failing for some reason. You cleared it right up, thank you!

Comment: This works perfectly thanks. Is it necessary to declare `const applyJSSRules = mockStyleInjection();` inside the test ? Or is it ok to declare at the top of the file (for multiple tests).

Answer (score 0):

This ultimately seems like an issue with [JSS](https://cssinjs.org) and various browser implementations like jsdom and and Blink (at least in Chrome). You can see it in Chrome when trying to modify/enable/disable these style rules (you can't).

The behavior appears to be a result of the JSS library using the [CSSOM insertRule API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule). There's a stylesheet generated in the DOM for the styles we expect in our component, but the tag is empty - it's just used to link the shadow CSS back to the DOM. The styles are never written to the inline stylesheet in the DOM, and as a result, the `getComputedStyle` method does not return the expected results.

There's [an open issue](https://github.com/cssinjs/jss/issues/1125) to address this behavior and make development easier.

I switched my custom components to [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/), which does not have some of these idiosyncrasies.
[Material-UI is planning on transitioning soon as well](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/6115).

Answer (score 0):

You could add this to a [custom render function](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup).  After rendering, the function pulls the styles out of [cssom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model) and puts them into a style tag.  Here is an implementation:

```
let customRender = (ui, options) => {
    let renderResult = render(ui, options);
    let styleElement = document.createElement("style");
    let styleText = "";
    for (let styleSheet of document.styleSheets) {
        for (let rule of styleSheet.cssRules) {
            styleText += rule.cssText + "\n";
        }
    }
    styleElement.textContent = styleText.slice(0, -1);
    document.head.appendChild(styleElement);
    // remove old style elements
    let emptyStyleElements = document.head.querySelectorAll('style[data-jss=""]');
    for (let element of emptyStyleElements) {
        element.remove();
    }
    return renderResult;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't speak specifically to Material-UI stylesheets, but you can inject a stylesheet into rendered component:

```js
import {render} from '@testing-library/react';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

const stylesheetFile = fs.reactFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../path-to-stylesheet'), 'utf-8');

const styleTag = document.createElement('style');
styleTag.type = 'text/css';
styleTag.innerHTML = stylesheetFile;

const rendered = render(<MyComponent>);
rendered.append(style);
```

You don't necessarily have to read from a file, you can use whatever text you want.